# Schedule DAG to run daily for last 30 days

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that runs daily at 11:00 AM. I want to pull the data for the last 30 days because it involves some running metrics who's value changes over time in the last 30 days. I am using Airflow 1.10.14 and Astronomer 1.10.14

```
 default_args = {
 'owner': 'airflow',
 'depends_on_past': False,
 'start_date': datetime(2017,11,13,9,11),
 'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
 'email_on_failure': False,
 'email_on_retry': False,
 'retries': 1,
 'retry_delay': timedelta(mintues=5)
}
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="data_refresh_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    description="daily pipeline for budget",
    schedule_interval='30 11 * * *',
)

task_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task_1",
    python_callable=task1_main().main,
    op_kwargs={'task1_cids': '{{ dag_run.conf["task1_cids"] }}'},
    dag=dag,
)


task_2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task_2",
    python_callable=task_2().main,
    op_kwargs={'task2_cids': '{{ dag_run.conf["task2_cids"] }}'},
    dag=dag,
)
```